# Probability of k heads given a biased coin, unknown bias

Tags: probability, bayesian

There are two biased coins, the probability of flipping heads for the first coin is *a*, the probability of flipping heads for the second coin is *b*. One of the coins is chosen at random, with probability *p* that the first coin is chosen. A Once the coin is chosen, it is flipped 3 times and *k* Heads are observed, where k = 0, 1, 2, 3.

What is the conditional probability that the first coin was chosen?

Letting X be the random variable representing the choice of the coin, and K be the random variable representing the number of heads, I understand that this is an application of a variation of Bayes' Rule:

$$
p_{X|K}(x|k) = \frac {p_X(x)p_{K|X}(k|x)}{\sum_{k'}p_X(x')p_{K|X}(k|x')}
$$

I know that the first term is substituted for *p*, from above: $$ p_X(x) = p $$

But I'm unsure how to evaluate: $$ p_{K|X}(k|x) $$
Having similar trouble interpreting the denominator.

Any help is much appreciated. Picking up a stat class late in the semester and struggling to get caught up. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional on the first coin being chosen, the probability of flipping $k$ heads is $\binom{3}{k}a^k(1-a)^{3-k}$, and conditional on the second coin being chosen, it is $\binom{3}{k}b^k(1-b)^{3-k}$. Thus, by Bayes' Rule, the probability of flipping $k$ heads is
$$
p\binom{3}{k}a^k(1-a)^{3-k}+(1-p)\binom{3}{k}b^k(1-b)^{3-k}.
$$
Thus, the conditional probability that the first coin was chosen given that $k$ heads were flipped is
$$
\frac{p\binom{3}{k}a^k(1-a)^{3-k}}{p\binom{3}{k}a^k(1-a)^{3-k}+(1-p)\binom{3}{k}b^k(1-b)^{3-k}}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Given $X$, that is given the probability of heads, the distribution of $K$ is binomial:
$$p_{K|X}(k|1)=\binom{3}{k}a^k(1-a)^{3-k}$$
$$p_{K|X}(k|2)=\binom{3}{k}b^k(1-b)^{3-k}$$

Answer (score 0):

Using your $X$ and your $K$, I will let $X = 1$ denote the event that the first coin was chosen and $X=0$ be the event that the second coin was chosen.
Then the problem is
\begin{align*}
P(X=1|K = k) &=\frac{P(X=1,K=k)}{P(K = k)}\\
&=\frac{P(K = k|X = 1)P(X=1)}{P(K = k, X = 0)+P(K=k, X = 1)}\\
&=\frac{P(K = k|X = 1)P(X=1)}{P(K = k|X=0)P(X = 0)+P(K=k| X = 1)P(X=1)}\\
&=\frac{\binom{3}{k}a^k(1-a)^{3-k}\cdot p}{\binom{3}{k}b^k(1-b)^{3-k}\cdot(1-p)+\binom{3}{k}a^k(1-a)^{3-k}\cdot p}
\end{align*}
wherein I notice that $K|X=1$ follows a binomial distribution with $n = 3$ and probability of success $a$; $K|X=0$ follows a binomial distribution with $n = 3$ and probability of success $b$; and in the denominator of the second line, I used the law of total probability.